# My Windows machine is unable to install PROJ 4.9.0 through the OSGeo4W program. What should I do?

Tags: python, cartopy, proj, geos, osgeo

I have followed all of their steps for Windows on their [website](https://proj.org/install.html). However, I am still not able to install Cartopy through pip, as pip says both PROJ and geos have not been installed. What should I do?

Comment: Why Proj 4.9? In OSWGeo4W, it is 6.3+ now.

Comment: @swatchai Correct, I just said so because Cartopy requires at least 4.9.0